# Difference between putting aes(x=…) in ggplot() or in geom()

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

What is the difference between putting aes(x=…) in ggplot() or in geom() (e.g. geom_histogram() below):

**1. in ggplot():**

```
ggplot(diamonds) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=500, aes(x=diamonds$price))+ 
  xlab("Diamond Price U$") + ylab("Frequency")+ 
  ggtitle("Diamond Price Distribution")
```

[image: The histogram of method A goes here]

**2. in the geom():**

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=diamonds$price)) + 
  geom_histogram(bidwidth= 500) + 
  xlab("Price") + ylab("Frequncy") + 
  ggtitle("Diamonds Price distribution")
```

[image: The histogram of method B goes here]

Comment: There's a typo in your second method. Change `bidwidth` to `binwidth` & they'll be the same.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, that's quite true.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you put `x = price` in the original `ggplot()` call or in a specific `geom` only really matters if you have multiple geoms with different mappings. The mapping you specify in the `ggplot()` call will be applied to all geoms, so it's often best to put the mapping in the top level like that, if only to save you having to type it out again for each individual geom. Specify mappings in the individual `geom`s if they only apply to that specific `geom`.

Also note that it should just be `aes(x = price)`, not `aes(x = diamonds$price)`. `ggplot` knows to look in the dataframe you're using as your `data` argument. If you pass a vector manually like `diamonds$price` you might mess up facetting or grouping in a more complex plot.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, it's quite helpful. Now I totally understand the difference. It is often best to add aes(x=, y= )in the ggplot() call to make sure that all geoms will be applied.